# Identify Most Recent Record on Yearly Snapshot by partition of Arrange Id

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I have Scenario Like below and want set Indicator based on Arrange Id, Login Date.. If User login website multiple time in Calendar Year then Most recent record need to set Y else N. Also I need to set Indicator like Bottom two rows as well.. ( Means 1121221 Accessed on last year recent 12/13/2017 need to set 'Y' and if user accessed in next immediate year 1/12/2018 then 'Y' )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9hif.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option. What does it do?

- the `TEST` CTE are some sample rows. Note `ARRANGE_ID = 999`, which has dates from 2017 and 2019 (which means that there are no consecutive years, so the date in 2019 should get the indicator 'N'. You didn't say, though, what would happen if there's yet another date in 2019; would both of them get 'N', or would the max login date still get a 'Y'?
- the `INTER` CTE uses the `MAX` analytic function to find the maximum login date for the year and the `LAG` analytic function which returns the previous login date (so that I could check whether those years are consecutive or not)
- the final query uses `CASE` to find whether certain row satisfies conditions to make the indicator equal to 'Y'

Here you go:

```
SQL> with test (arrange_id, login_date) as
  2    (select 234, date '2017-02-18' from dual union all
  3     select 234, date '2017-04-13' from dual union all
  4     select 234, date '2017-11-14' from dual union all
  5     select 234, date '2018-01-14' from dual union all
  6     select 234, date '2018-09-11' from dual union all
  7     select 234, date '2019-04-02' from dual union all
  8     select 234, date '2019-05-18' from dual union all
  9     select 112, date '2017-02-23' from dual union all
 10     select 112, date '2017-12-13' from dual union all
 11     select 112, date '2018-01-12' from dual union all
 12     select 999, date '2017-01-01' from dual union all
 13     select 999, date '2017-05-25' from dual union all
 14     select 999, date '2019-01-01' from dual
 15    ),
 16  inter as
 17    (select arrange_id,
 18       login_date,
 19       max(login_date) over
 20         (partition by arrange_id, extract (year from login_date)) maxdate,
 21       lag(login_date) over (partition by arrange_id order by login_date) prev_date
 22     from test
 23    )
 24  select arrange_id,
 25    login_date,
 26    case when login_date = maxdate and
 27              extract(year from login_date) - extract(year from prev_date) <= 1 then 'Y'
 28         else 'N'
 29    end indicator
 30  from inter
 31  order by arrange_id, login_date;

ARRANGE_ID LOGIN_DATE I
---------- ---------- -
       112 02/23/2017 N
       112 12/13/2017 Y  -- Y because it is MAX in 2017
       112 01/12/2018 Y  -- Y because it is MAX in 2018 and 2018 follows 2017
       234 02/18/2017 N
       234 04/13/2017 N
       234 11/14/2017 Y  -- Y because it is MAX in 2017
       234 01/14/2018 N
       234 09/11/2018 Y  -- Y because it is MAX in 2018 and 2018 follows 2017
       234 04/02/2019 N
       234 05/18/2019 Y  -- Y because it is MAX in 2019 and 2019 follows 2018
       999 01/01/2017 N
       999 05/25/2017 Y  -- Y because it is MAX in 2017
       999 01/01/2019 N  -- N because it is MAX in 2019, but 2019 doesn't follow 2017

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```